# WPF Web browser lambda event not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, lambda

I am trying to authenticate a login and did not want to make a even handler for this. I would like the the method to return the Authcode but the lambda expression inner code does not seem to execute. Any help is appreciated :)

```
Auth.Navigate(loginUri);

Auth.Navigated += delegate(object o, NavigationEventArgs e)  {
     //This code never seems to exacute
     fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out OAuth);
     fb.AccessToken = OAuth.AccessToken;
};

return OAuth.AcessToken;
```

Comment: what happen if you put `Auth.Navigated += ...` before the `Auth.Navigate()` ...

Comment: And what do you mean "never seems to execute"? Is it to hard to put a breakpoint, or at least a log to know if it is executed or not?

Comment: Sorry i should have phrased that better. it does not execute! yes I did place breakpoints on it as well as Debug.WriteLine it never enters. And i shall try registering the event first.